# Scroll and selecting specific value from a pickerWheel appium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

the following does work BUT when I used the **scrollObject.Add("name", "Mon, Apr 9")**, it won't go that specific value from the pickerWheel.

```
Dictionary<string, object> scrollObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
scrollObject.Add("direction", "down");
scrollObject.Add("element", ((RemoteWebElement)el));
scrollObject.Add("name", "Mon, Apr 9");  --> ERROR HERE
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Does anyone know how to implement the mobile: selectPickerWheel or mobile: scroll, moving the control to a specific value??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to manually scroll to be able to click an element is not displayed.

I made something similar but with Python:

```
self.touchAction = TouchAction(self.driver)
self.touchAction.press(None, x, self.screenHeight/4).move_to(None, 0, ((self.screenHeight/4)*-1)+1).release().perform()
```

In your case you won't have to use screenHeight or screenWidth. Instead you will have to use your ((RemoteWebElement)el) element width, height and size.